# Are question about job outside academia but related to on topic?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a question about seeking for a job. This job is outside academia, but require many academia skills (such as math, able to deep research, etc). Is this kind of question on topic here? If not, is there a site should I ask instead?

Comment: Could you perhaps say a bit more about this job?  It's hard to answer when it's so vague, since you could be talking about anything from industrial labs (clearly on topic) to marketing (clearly off topic).

Comment: It can be labs, or R&D that require to have satistic background.

Comment: If you're looking toward an R&D career, it generally counts as academia for this site.

Comment: jakebeal is correct. However, if in doubt, you can post a sample version of the question in the chat room—or edit your question above to include the draft text of what you want to know. We can tell you what's likely to happen on the main site. . . .

Comment: @aeismail It seems that no answer gets a significant number of votes, so I don't really know which one the community choose so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4):

As a rule of thumb, I think that if a job entails publishing in academic journals or work that supports or eventually will lead to that goal, then it's on-topic. Anything that isn't at least tangentially related to that it probably isn't on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking help regarding to an R&D job in which people engage in many of the same actions as academia (e.g., scientific research, peer-reviewed publishing, research funding applications), then that job is likely to be considered part of "greater academia" for the purposes of this site.

Comment: is analysis data considered to be scientific research?

Comment: @Ooker It depends what you're analyzing.  If you're analyzing a marketing campaign or planning trading for a hedge-fund, then no.  If you're analyzing scientific data, then yes.  In between, maybe you can give a little more information rather than being so vague?

Comment: If I know which one are good for me, then maybe I don't need to ask anymore. But I think that I should research deeper before asking. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, questions about job-seeking outside of academia are not on topic. You may want to try checking out [Workplace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

I'm sure there are some counter-examples where questions like this were on topic; if you find any that you want to have clarified, feel free to post in the comments and we can discuss.

Comment: is the job on [this list](http://www.aip.org/statistics/common-job-titles-physics-bachelors) are on topic? And what about R&D?

Comment: @Ooker Some of them are and some of them aren't.

Comment: @eykanal: We have established that research careers outside of academia are the main exception to this general prescription.